# Eclipse formatter doesn't respect line width

Tags: eclipse

I'm using eclipse luna (4.4). I have a java line that looks like this:

```
LongClassName obj = new LongClassName(new AnotherLongName(), new YetAnotherLongNAme());
```

This line is longer than my line width, so i would like to configure the formatter to fix this. 
Unfortunately, the formatter keeps changing it to:

```
LongClassName obj = 
    new LongClassName(new AnotherLongName(), new YetAnotherLongNAme());
```

Which is problematic because the second line is **still longer** than my line width.

I would like the formatter to wrap the argument list, like so:

```
LongClassName obj = 
    new LongClassName(new AnotherLongName(), 
                      new YetAnotherLongNAme());
```

However, i can't figure out how to do that.
I tried changing the policy fields in "Formatter -> Line Wrapping -> Function Calls", but it doesn't help.
Enabling or disabling the "Prefer warpping outer expressions..." option doesn't change the result either.

I don't want to resort to on/off tags or to use "Never join already wrapped lines", I want the formatter to do it automatically.

Edit:

I'd rather not force the formatter to wrap all function calls, only those that exceed the line width. E.g. this:

```
Foo f = new Foo(4, 7);
```

should stay as it is, and not be wrapped.

Answer (score 1):

Formatter -> Line Wrapping -> Function Calls

set: `Line wrapping policy:` to `Wrap all elements, except first element if not necessary (5 of 5)`

check: `Force split, even if line shorter than maximum line width`

set: `Indentation policy` to `Indent on column`

this way you do not need to change `Maximum line width`

if you want also right side of assignment (new LongClasssName... in your case) to wrap you should also do the followings:

Formatter -> Line Wrapping -> Expressions -> Assignements

set: `Line wrapping policy:` to `Wrap first element, others when necessary`

check: `Force split, even if line shorter than maximum line width`

set: `Indentation policy` to `Indent by one`

p.s: you should apply only this changes to `Eclipse [built-in]` settings

Comment: This does help, however it will wrap all instances, even something as silly as 'new Foo(4, 6)'. I guess I should edit the question.